# What determines the pixel depth of Chrome/Mac outline focus ring style?

Tags: css, google-chrome, focus, accessibility, user-agent

I have a bit of a bug where some members in my team see focus styles differently on the same element. They are running Chrome 86 on Mac. I am running Chrome 79.

When this specific element is focused, I see the basic focus ring I am used to, the blue glow at a depth of 5px

[image: a focus ring with a blue glow and a depth of 5px]

My colleagues however see a very narrow 2px border around the focused element.

The code for the element is:

```
<button>
    <img ... />
</button>
```

The image inside the button has `overflow:hidden` applied in order to give the appearance of a centre crop.

Here is a snippet

```css
button {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1062/100/50">
</button>
```

I'm trying to understand what the cause of the change in user agent stylesheet settings is and why it would cause this difference.

The focus style I see:

```
outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
```

My colleagues see:

```
outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 2px;
```

However, this isn't universal on their browsers. They see the 5px on other elements.

I don't really want to start adding new focus styles as I'd prefer to honour the browser's own settings in case the user has specified a focus style that works for them.

**My main questions**

1. What causes the browser to choose the thickness of the focus ring?
2. Could the `overflow:hidden` on the image inside be the cause of this bug?
3. Why don't I see the issue on Chrome 79?

Comment: maybe you could provide CSS and HTML to reproduice ?

Comment: @MaxiGui here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/asos-francesca/pen/JjKNYWX?editors=1100

Comment: Why are you running Chrome 79? It's obsolete already. 90%+ of your users will already be on Chrome 85+ by now.

Comment: @Dai I normally just wait for Chrome to say there is an update before I do so. However, I haven't had any notification to update Chrome so I'm still on 79.

Comment: @user1486133 You may have installed an Enterprise version of Chrome with automatic updates disabled or otherwise disabled automatic updates (malware can do that to ensure you remain vulnerable, btw  - you may want to run a virus scan). Chrome 79 is almost a year old now which is ancient-history in Chrome's development timeline. You should open Menu > Help > About and see why it says it isn't updating. Also check that you haven't disabled Chrome's auto-update system-services.

Answer (score 1):

> What causes the browser to choose the thickness of the focus ring?

The browser's built-in stylesheet ("user-agent styles"). **This is liable to change with every major browser update** - it's also platform-specific (e.g. Chrome 86 on Mac will render things differently to Chrome 86 on Windows 10) - so you must not depend on any particular user-agent stylesheet rules for your webpage to render correctly.

> Could the `overflow:hidden` on the image inside be the cause of this bug?

I doubt it.

> Why don't I see the issue on Chrome 79?

[Because Chrome changed their user-agent styles for `:focus` and `:focus-visible` in Chrome 86](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/09/giving-users-and-developers-more.html).

Comment: But it chooses a different thickness of the ring on different elements, even within Chrome 86. What determines the thickness chosen for each element? Why would it choose 5px on some, and 2px on others.

Comment: @user1486133 Please read the linked article. `:focus` and `:focus-visible` have subtly different styles and are triggered by different UI events.

Answer (score 1):

Chromium was updated earlier this year with a fresh look.

You can [read about the design updates here](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/03/updates-to-form-controls-and-focus.html). This is one (of many factors) that can account for different user agent stylesheets.

However be aware that just because you see one thing, your colleagues see another that those are the only options.

My focus ring is only 1px and black, so that gives you an idea of how varied styles are (Chrome 86.0.4240.111 on Windows).

### Accessibility

The more important part of your question is the part where you don't want to "interfere" with the browser default styles.

> I don't really want to start adding new focus styles as I'd prefer to honour the browser's own settings in case the user has specified a focus style that works for them.

This just doesn't work in the real world. What if your website has a blue background? (Yes I am aware browsers are becoming smarter at accounting for this but in accessibility [we need to support all the way back to IE8!](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey8/#browsers)). Also what if you have a complex widget that changes colour?

Style focus so that it is appropriate for the website, you want a contrast ratio of at least 3:1 on surrounding items. For really complex sites you may need a different focus ring colour depending on the background location to maintain this contrast ratio.

### Style your focus rings!

@Dai made a valid point that this section was not very clear initially.

When I say to "style your focus rings" I mean to make them more usable and prominent than browser defaults.

Consider where they are placed on the page (their surroundings) to ensure sufficient colour contrast (as mentioned earlier 3:1 minimum with surroundings) and make sure they are clearly visible (they are called visible focus indicators for a reason).

As @Dai said, don't use this as an opportunity to try and flex your creative muscles, 20px wide magenta focus rings are not needed (and possibly might not be accessible). Keep them simple and **consistent** across the site.

**Above all remember that focus indicators are there for accessibility.**

I tend to advocate for an outline of 2px and an outline offset of 2px to ensure it is visible as the slight bit of white space around the item makes it easier to see.

```css
button {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

.better:focus{
  outline: 2px solid #333;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<h2>no image standard button</h2>

<button>
  button with text
</button>

<h2>standard</h2>

<button>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1062/100/50">
</button>

<h2>better</h2>
<button class="better">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1062/100/50">
</button>
```

Oh and `:focus-visible` will be great when it gets traction but at the [moment it doesn't have very good support](https://caniuse.com/css-focus-visible) so make sure you polyfill it if you use it.

Comment: "Style your focus rings!" - I'm not sure I want every amateur unfamiliar with WCAG to suddenly start doing `*:focus-visible { border: 20px inset magenta; }` complete with an obnoxious `@keyframes` animation to boot. **Personally I'd rather no-one styled accessibility elements** - y'know, so that they will remain *accessibility* elements rather than *aesthetic* elements.

Comment: Haha yeah true, perhaps I need to be a little more clear with that point, I have added a bit to that section to hopefully get your point across. The sentiment was right, browser default focus indicators are not actually as accessible as they could be, but I don't want anyone misconstruing my meaning and creating 20px magenta focus rings either!

Comment: Thanks, I had already discovered the use of outline-offset to "fix" the bug but was being tentative about making changes that affect default focus styling as I would always prefer the user have control over their own a11y settings. I was trying to get to the bottom of why this was happening to see if I could adjust my code in a way to make the whole Chrome86 ring visible in its entirety, and not be clipped. I still don't understand why it's clipping it when the container is rendered in full, not clipped like its inside image?

Comment: This is pure conjecture but it looks like because the image is the same width as the button the image appears in front of the focus indicator and partially blocks it. Very difficult to tell as the inspector will always show the same value for the focus ring. As for users controlling their a11y settings, that is a bit of misnomer, if they use a custom style sheet as an override it will override whatever you set anyway so you won't interfere. However 99% of users won't do this and so will have to put up with (the less than ideal) focus indicators the browser supplies if you don't set them.

Comment: Actually I just checked this by using a magnifier, the focus indicator is ever so slightly inset (so half inside and half outside at 1CSS px width). Now if you set it to 5px wide it is basically 4.5px outside and 0.5px inside. So the image appears to be partially covering it as I suspected. If you make the image 99px by 99px with a 0.5px margin the focus indicator is the same (although you get the button showing through ever so slightly). I added a second example to the "standard" section to illustrate this.

Answer (score 0):

The outline on focus if it is not set in CSS is actualy decided by the browser settings.

[Here](https://allyjs.io/tests/focus-outline-styles/#style=focus&key=button&browser=firefox,chrome,safari,ie11) you can see already differents behave from a browser to another on windows and Mac. So I would not be surprise that this settings are changing from a version to another.